# How to take annotated screenshots with keyboard only?

Tags: image-manipulation, screenshot

Workflow:

1. Take a screenshot.
2. Select a region on the screenshot (an overlay displays keys).
3. Input a text.
4. Repeat step #2 or save/imgur upload.

All steps should be handled by keyboard only.

Does something like that exist?

Answer (score -1):

I use Spectacle, part of KDE Application Suit. Set a keyboard shortcut to launch it. Default `print sreen`. It takes a screenshot immidiately as launched and have annotation option.

Comment: Why downvote ? Have I missed something? Spectacle does exactly what is mentioned, if I have understood properly.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Are all steps done by keyboard only, i.e. no mouse? Because he wants it done by keyboard. I do not know this Spectacle tool, so I ask, and might therefore revert the downvote into upvote. Cheers.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that point completely. I put emphasise on annotation. My bad.